# Intellisense broken for some XAML files

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, autocomplete, resharper, intellisense

I was using a Resharper trial in Visual Studio 2010 that expired.  After it expired, Intellisense was broken and a number of settings such as '***Open With***' were restored to defaults.  I re-enabled Intellisense features that I was familiar with for C# files by checking the boxes '**Auto list members**' and '**Parameter information**' under **Options->Text Editor->All Languages**.

I still do not get the autocompletion behavior that I expect within XAML files of my existing solutions.  When starting to type a tag, '<', I normally expect to see a list of types that are in the scope of the XML namespace.  I do see some autocompletion options, but they are limited to `<!--`, `<![CDATA[`, and `<?`.  When typing property names and values I don't get any options.

When I create a new solution with xaml files, Intellisense behaves as expected.  I have disabled the few extensions that I have installed to no effect.  Restarting VS and my system also hasn't made any difference.

Can anyone offer any methods of troublehooting Intellisense?

Edit: I should also mention that Visual Studio does not prevent me from editing XAML files while debugging in the cases that Intellisense is not working.  This may be a good hint at what is going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Export your settings under tools -> Import and Export Settings.  Do it in groups of functionality.  Then use Import and Export Settings to reset all your settings and re-import your settings a bit at a time to figure out where the issue is.

Comment: Exported all settings, reset all settings to defaults, restarted, and I still see the same behavior.

Comment: Strange...  I gave up on fixing the problem for the day and imported the settings I desired from my earlier export and re-enabled my extensions.  After leaving my computer for 30 minutes, I came back and everything was working.  I didn't restart Visual Studio or even close the current buffer I was working in.